# How to pass a Json object into webservice method

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

I have the below web method in a .asmx web service.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = false)]
public virtual ServiceResponse GetTest([FromBody]Test request){}
```

model

```
public class Test{
 public string parameter1 { get; set; }
 public string parameter2 { get; set; }
}
```

When testing with Postman it works when I pass the below Json

```
{
  "request":
  {
  "parameter1" : "param1",
  "parameter2" : "param12",
  }
}
```

How can I get rid of the "request" in the Json? If I remove it, then I get the error missing value for parameter: 'request'.

I want to have the Json like below

```
{  
  "parameter1" : "param1",
  "parameter2" : "param12"      
}
```

Comment: The request is the parameter name that you have as the argument. Thus you need to mention the argument name.

Comment: I'm not familiar with WCF. Is it possible you use WebInvoke with WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare?